# Classification of multidimensional data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, training-data, supervised-learning

I would like to classify some multidimensional data:

The input data is as follows:

```
Data1: [[a1,b1,f1], [a2,b2,f2], ... [an,bn,fn]] where: fn = F(an,bn) --> ClassA
Data2: [[c1,d1,g1], [c2,d2,g2], ... [cn,dn,gn]] where: gn = G(cn,dn) --> ClassB
...
```

So, given Datax, as follows, we would like to classify it into one of the finite classes we have:

```
Datax: [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], ... [xn,yn,zn]] where: zn = Z(xn,yn) --> which class?
```

I could probably flatten the array for each record and train my classifier:

```
Data1: [a1,b1,f1,a2,b2,f2,...,an,bn,fn]
```

But I thought because the third values themselves are a function of the first two values (e.g. `fn = F(an,bn)`), I should consider that relationship in my training rather than going for a flat array.

Does it make any difference? or what is the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the 3rd data of each tuple is the product of the same deterministic function (that can be different in each row but must the same for each triple of the row)
then you can simply cut of zn because it does not bring any new information.

ex: z1 = 3x1 + 2y1 ; z2 = 3x1 + 2y1 ; [...] ; zn = 3xn + 2yn

If it is not the case then you should leave z1.

Said this, I think you can flatten the array because most models would automatically understand those kind of dependancies.

Comment: thanks, but yes, the functions are different for every class, but we don't know what they are. Actually, I've simplified the problem and I fear that by flattening the array, the model cannot find the dependencies. Basically, n==200, which makes every record an array of 600 numbers. So, in every class we have some data records each of which composed of an array of 600 numbers where 200 numbers are a function of the other 400 number `zn = F (xn,yn)` and such functions are the same for the records of a class, but different across different classes